# Whats the easiest way to reactive a submit() action that was cancelled with 'return false'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some image buttons that have jQuery event handlers attached to them.

I want to make an AJAX call in the click() event to determine if the action should actually be allowed. Because I am doing an async ajax call I have to return 'false' to immediately cancel the event and wait for the response.

```
$('[id^=btnShoppingCartStep_]').click(function() {

 var stepName = this.id.substring("btnShoppingCartStep_".length);

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $.url("isActionAllowed"),
            data: "requestedStep=" + stepName,
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(data) {

                if (data.allowed) {

                    // need to resume the action here
                }
                else {
                    AlertDialog(data.message, "Not allowed!");
                }

            }

        });

        return false;
    });
```

I need to find the best way to resume the click event if the AJAX call determines that it should be allowed.

Any way of doing this that I can come up with seems clumsy, such as :

1) remove event handler from the buttons

2) simulate a click on the button that was clicked

Is there any nice way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Why can't you check that in the background before user ever wants to click the "Submit"? Also consider doing blocked request instead.

Comment: why don't you try Block UI [http://malsup.com/jquery/block/]?

Answer (score 1):

How long does it take to confirm the validity of the request? What else would be the user be doing during that time?

Why not have the server do the validation? Is that too risky? You could simply pass the data along to the server, have it determine if it's valid. If it's not, it tells Ajax "not allowed", the function alerts the user. If it liked the data, there is no need to resume the action as it's already done.

Comment: thanks for the extra info. there will be additional server side validation - i just dont want users to lose any choices they already may have made on the current page when they try to go to another page they may nto be allowed to go to.

i dont have time right now to duplicate the server side logic entirely in javascript. its more a courtesy to the user than anythin the way i'm implementing it now.

Answer (score 1):

if you need submit form:

```
$('#form_id').submit();
```

if you need continue this function:

```
var allowed_actions = {};

$('[id^=btnShoppingCartStep_]').click(function() {

var stepName = this.id.substring("btnShoppingCartStep_".length);
var $click_me_again = $(this);

if (!allowed_actions[stepName]) {
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: $.url("isActionAllowed"),
          data: "requestedStep=" + stepName,
          dataType: "json",

          success: function(data) {

            if (data.allowed) {

                // need to resume the action here
                allowed_actions[stepName] = true;
                $click_me_again.click();
            }
            else {
                AlertDialog(data.message, "Not allowed!");
            }

          }

      });
      return false;
    } // end if
    // continue function (check passed)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to your form.  Let's say you name it `myForm`.  Where your `// need to resume the action here` is, use this:

```
$("#myForm").trigger("submit");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Simply call the form's submit() method.

```
$("#FormID").submit();
```

2) Also, if what you want is to intercept form submissions for that for, you may want to do this slightly differently (e.g. if you can submit the form via >1 button):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  ...
```